# Fastest way to determine whether an element is contained in a multimap?

Tags: c++, multimap

Assume a multimap<string, string>. I want to test whether an element, say pair<string, string>("foo", "bar") is contained. Sure I can go with something like

```
auto range(myMap.equal_range("foo"));
auto it = find(range.first, range.second, pair<string, string>("foo", "bar"));
```

but that would mean linear search within range. Since the multimap should be ordered I would prefer to benefit from the order and search with logarithmic complexity. Is that possible?

Comment: Once you have the range (i.e. all entries with the same key) you have to do a linear search to find the matching value - there is no alternative. `std::multimap` uses insertion order for matching keys, so may be you can organize your inserts to insert most frequently used items first(?)...

Comment: multimaps are mostly binary trees and therefore must have some order on the values with the same key as well. I was thinking that there should be a way to search an profit from the order at least if the implementation provides one.

Comment: As I said, the order is insertion order.

Comment: Since no-one else is asking, I will. What is the replicated load frequency of duplicate keys? Part of the ins-speed of a multi-map is the fact that replicated keys are *not* sorted and rather are maintained in insertion order. If this is a commonality, you may be better off using a composite `std::set<std::pair<K<T>>` with an appropriate comparator. If "does-key-exist" is frequent and the replicate-load is low, a `std::map<K,std::vector<T>>` where the mapped-to value `T` is maintained  in sorted order *by you* may be a better fit. It would help to know more about the problem you're solving.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I understand what you mean, but my question was not, what is the best container for the purpose. It is just whether it is possible to avoid linear search for that specific task and as it turns out the answer seems to be no. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. I see, then no, it isn't If you're distinct *pair* search-heavy I would use a composite key and/or a different container. If you're pinned exclusively to `std::multimap` I'm afraid you're sol.

Comment: Some sound suggestions for alternative containers already.  More trivially, using `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` and iterating across the range until you find either a match, end/rend or another key can be better than using `equal_range` and having to find both endpoints up front, albeit depending on key comparison speed and exact cache/memory performance impacts....

Comment: @WhozCraig: Nim already proposed map<string, set<string>> which is not pretty but the best idea up to now IMO.

Comment: @KitFisto It isn't equivalent. Using that construct you can't have identical keys *and* values like you can in a `multimap`, and if it is a better match for what you're trying to do, it is more fuel to the cause that a `multimap` isn't the right container in the first place. If that self-managed solution were functionally equivalent to `multimap` *and* solved you linear search-on-identical-keys problem, I would have up voted it myself.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I dont need the ability to insert identical values. Even when I do not I will usually use multimap because there is no simple alternative.

Comment: @WhozCraig: And if I needed that ability (and the ability to search for the key as well), wouldn't map<string, multiset<string>> be the best approach?

Comment: @KitFisto that detail (no duplicate-value requirements) was left out of the original question, and yes, that would likely be the best match to what you're trying to do. If all keys have values, however, a proper comparator and a composite key would equally suffice (and in fact likely be even better). However, as you said, all you were looking for was an is-this-possible-with `std::multimap` and I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a typical pattern of access, I would say that the `multimap` is the wrong container?

Something like the following may be more appropriate?

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>
```

Okay, insertion and removal is more complex, but a find matches the requirements that you have.

Answer (score 0):

You want to simply use `find()`:

```
 multimap<T> m;
 T t;
 // ...
 multimap<T>::iterator r = m.find(t);
 if (r != m.end()) {
     // hit
 }
```

Comment: I want to search for the value not just the key. Otherwise I could also use find or count.

Comment: Also, [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) requires two non-optional template parameters, including the key and value types.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees on the relative order of elements with equivalent keys in C++98 so depending on your build environment, you're looking at linear complexity for searching the range.

You could use a custom `multimap` by creating a `map` that maps to a `set`:

```
// std namespace removed for brevity
map< string, set<string> > myMap;
```

This might be useful if you expect lots of values with the same keys. Otherwise, your original solution looks nicer as iterating this isn't as clean. Should write a function for searching this container.

Answer (score -1):

Multimaps are typically implemented as red-black trees (GNU C++ does this). Doing a search on them through their iterators will thus be O(log n).

Comment: Once the matching range is found for a given key, the search is linear not logarithmic..

Comment: The algorithm find is always linear. Could you explain how I could perform the "search through the iterator"?